# The working copy '<Project Name>' failed to commit files - Couldnt communicate with helper application

Tags: xcode, git, commit, xcode7

I've just updated to Xcode 7 general release and ive tried committing files. Its failing however, and im getting the following message;

[image]

Ive seen this question but the secondary response is different in the OP question: [Xcode and Git Source Control : “The working copy XXXXX failed to commit files”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694662/xcode-and-git-source-control-the-working-copy-xxxxx-failed-to-commit-files)

Whats the 'helper application' that it is looking for and whats the solution? Migrating to Xcode 7 and iOS9 is becoming a headache :(
I commit my files by going to 'Source Control' -> 'Commit'

Comment: try this :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694662/xcode-and-git-source-control-the-working-copy-xxxxx-failed-to-commit-files

Comment: @Nanthakumaran this question has a different second message, as ive said above.

Comment: Can you see these two processes  `com.apple.dt.Xcode.sourcecontrol.WorkingCopyScanner` and  `com.apple.dt.Xcode.sourcecontrol.SSHHelper` in activity monitor?

Comment: @AnthonyKong Yes both seem to be there.

Comment: @AnthonyKong they are using 0.0 CPU though so it looks like they are not booting up

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Turns out the “helper application” is in fact Git. For some reason Xcode 7 is eager to associate you (the committer) with a name and an email address.

To fix it, on the command line, type the following:

```
xcrun git config --global user.email you@yourdomain.com
xcrun git config --global user.name "Your Name Here"
```

Comment: I recently ran into this and found that if I restarted xcode then I was able to do the commits just fine.

Comment: I had the same problem with Xcode 9. After having read your advice, I simply went to Preferences → Source Control → Git and replaced the "Author Name" and "Author Email" fields with the same content they already had. This apparently had the same effect as the shell commands.

Comment: One should be careful about using --global though as this sets the info for all projects, and that might not be what you want. To set it to a specific project, locate your project inte the terminal, then simply omit the global command: `git config user.name "myName"`

Comment: I did what micah wrote about just restarting the xcode and it worked fine for me as well and i was able to do a commit and push. thanks!

Answer (score 19):

If the above mentioned solutions don't work, try this one:

Add changes once with a git command. Use terminal and change to your working directory (that contains a /.git folder) and execute:

```
git commit -a -m "Commit title here"
```

After that commit via Xcode should work again.

Comment: Thanks this is the solution for me

Comment: Thank you! You are the wind beneath my wings. Other solutions didn't work.

Comment: a good solution, fixes this problem

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem.

This fixed my problem: Quit Xcode(using CMD+Q) & run it again.

Comment: worked for me Xcode Version 12.5.1 (12E507)

Answer (score 7):

The above solution did not work for me. I am running on Xcode 8 (8C1002) and I have close to 4500 files to commit at once (adding the sources of a library to my project).

The only way I can make it working (without the error message) is by committing smaller number of files multiple times instead of all at once.

Comment: I had around 3800 files to commit and had similar problems. Committing in 2 or 3 chunks seemed to work.

Answer (score 4):

This happens to me when I add new image assets.
The "fix" is to go to File > Save BEFORE you do a Git Commit.
Then the Commit works Fine.

Answer (score 1):

first you check in command line follow this picture .If git is clean (add . + commit done)

[image]

[image]

also have problem same you ForceQuit Xcode and open again