# The working copy '<Project Name>' failed to commit files - Couldn't communicate with helper application - Solution not working

Tags: xcode, git, git-commit

I am referring to a previous question with answers:
[The working copy '<Project Name>' failed to commit files - Couldnt communicate with helper application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32649277/the-working-copy-project-name-failed-to-commit-files-couldnt-communicate-w)

Yet, the answer does not work for me. I am new to Git. I got the initial version of the app from GitHub through Xcode 8. Then I made multiple copies of the project folder using Finder (My bad. Very bad way of doing it!) Now I want to commit one of these new projects to a new branch. But I keep getting the mentioned error. I did the xcrun inside the my current project folder and added email and name. -l lists fine with additions. Still getting the same error. git config --global -l does not work saying there is no such file or directory. when I run the xcrun in global mode it run without issues and then when I do -l I do not get a error but only the new parameters I set in the Git config file.

Please help me to commit and push changes.
Thanks in advance!

P.S. I have committed once before successfully. I think it is before I made the duplicates of the project file with finder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this solution: [Xcode 9 commit: Couldn't communicate with helper application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46607843/xcode-9-commit-couldnt-communicate-with-helper-application/46947162#46947162)

The solution is to add changes with a git command. Change to your working directory (that contains a /.git folder) and execute:

```
git commit -a -m "Commit title here"
```