# Xcode 9 commit: Couldn't communicate with helper application

Tags: git, macos, git-commit, xcode9

I've recently updated to OSX Sierra (from El Capitan) and to Xcode 9. I removed all compatibility issues (like autolayout issues) and would like to commit to my local gitrep now.

the following error appears:

[image]

I thought it might be the same bug appeared in XCode 7 mentioned here:
[Xcode and Git Source Control : “The working copy XXXXX failed to commit files”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694662/xcode-and-git-source-control-the-working-copy-xxxxx-failed-to-commit-files)

[image]

But it wasn't. I tried the solution mentioned above. Username and EMail are properly set. I did save everything, tried restarting the machine and a few other minor things. Nothing worked - i can't commit.

Any help appreciated.

**EDIT**

I got it to work by commiting manually and adding changes before with

```
git commit -a -m "Fixes"
```

I will keep an eye on that if it happens again once i made more changes and report here if so.

Comment: thank you so much, had the same issue and this worked.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The solution is to add changes once with a git command.
Use terminal and navigate to Xcode project folder. If you are in the right folder, this command:

```
ls -al
```

will list a .git folder. Then you know you're at the right place. Then execute

```
git commit -a -m "Commit title here"
```

After that commit via Xcode should work again.

Comment: for me commit is done via terminal, but still issue is coming for Xcode. I have to do that again n again via terminal. any solution?

Comment: I tried using source tree to commit but it didn't fix xcode problem, you'll need use terminal its true.

Comment: I had the same problem after upgrading to Xcode 10.2 
Setting the name and email from the terminal worked for me:

 
$ xcrun git config --global user.name "your name"    
$ xcrun git config --global user.email your.email@example.com  
[No double quotes in email]

After that i had to restart Xcode and it was working fine again.

Answer (score 30):

For me I had to populate Full Name and Email address in Preferences > Source Control > GIT (tab). They were blank.

Comment: even though this wasn't the question asked, this helped me thanks

Comment: this is the *only* solution that I came across, thanks!

Comment: it isnt. Although it is the solution for others and the same issues the question excludes this answer as already tested.

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me. But I had to do this, THEN create the project. It was much simpler, safer, than trying to fix the un-SCM'd project.

Comment: I should also note that I had ALREADY populated those fields in a previous version of Xcode, but Xcode 10.2.1 emptied those fields, leading to their (terribly named) error. Xcode... the perennial beta.

Comment: If you cant change the git name in Xcode, check here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55691470/6108739

Answer (score 10):

If you cant change the git name in Xcode, you can change username and email using the terminal:

```
xcrun git config --global user.name 'new_user_name'
xcrun git config --global user.email 'new@email.com'
```

And restart Xcode.

Comment: My entries of name and email were not being saved by Xcode 10.2.1 in the GIT tab as described above. With Xcode open I executed the commands above in terminal, restarted Xcode and the commit problem was solved. Much appreciated Vladyslav.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the Preferences> Source Control > Git > Ignored Files had the Watchkit Extension Complications Controller. Removing it from Ignored Files fixed the problem. Xcode 10.1, Watch OS 4.2.

Answer (score 0):

the problem that I had was whenever I tried to create source control it show Couldn’t communicate with a helper application. 
so in Xcode preferences I go to accounts and there I see I was logged out I signed in again and save the project, after closing the project and force quitting Xcode I opened it again and now it works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was creating remote repository but unable to send data.

In Xcode I re-added the remote repository myself using SSH connection. Then push and the result was successful. (Xcode Version 14.2)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

And push again.