# Xcode 9 - Couldn’t communicate with a helper application

Tags: ios, xcode, git

After updating some libraries have a strange problem. Xcode seems to have now a problem with two framework files (GooglePlaces.framework and GoogleMapsBase.framework).

[image]

It recognizes that they have changed but is totally reluctant to commit with the message: "Couldn’t communicate with a helper application." (If I unselect them I can commit without problems) Have someone experiences this?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to add changes with a git command. Change to your working directory (that contains a /.git folder) and execute:

```
git commit -a -m "Commit title here"
```

After that your git should work as usual.
In one case i had to remove and re-add the framework.

Answer is from this thread: [Xcode 9 commit: Couldn't communicate with helper application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46607843/xcode-9-commit-couldnt-communicate-with-helper-application/46947162#46947162)

Comment: Yes, I already found out that I sometimes need to fix things outside of Xcode. But it shouldn't be like that.

Comment: Worked perfectly!  Because it wasn't clear to me at first, just want to mention that you still need to push to the git.  I was able to do that within Xcode after running this command in Terminal.