# Xcode 9.3 export code signing and assets failed

Tags: ios, xcode

We try Xocde on two computers, all failed, The same error message is following:
"Could't communicate with a helper application." Need your help!

It's not the same problem as " Xcode 9 commit: Couldn't communicate...", this error occur when I try to export my code signing assets.

I have restartd Xocde, rbooted Mac, not working.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode 9 commit: Couldn't communicate with helper application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46607843/xcode-9-commit-couldnt-communicate-with-helper-application)

Comment: Did you try restarting Xcode? Rebooting your Mac?

Comment: It's not the same problem as " Xcode 9 commit: Couldn't communicate...", I have restartd Xocde, rbooted Mac, not working.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the only solution to my knowledge that works as of now is to reinstall Xcode 9.2 (from https://developer.apple.com, Downloads -> See More Downloads, search for Xcode 9.2) and then export as usual. Luckily, both version can co-exist.

Comment: Exporting on 9.2 worked for me - hopefully this gets fixed on an upcoming release

Comment: UPDATE: with the recent Xcode update **9.3.1 (9E501)** from 5/10/2018, the export works again!