# How to see commit crash logs in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, git, github, version-control, bitbucket

For some reason Xcode is not able to commit the frameworks (Pods) that I just updated, while my own source code is committed & pushed successfully to our git repository. I'm wondering whether it is possible to somehow have more information than the standard message popping up : `The working copy “MyApp” failed to commit files. Couldn’t communicate with a helper application.`.

I already tried to go look in : `~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/`but only the crashes from xcode itself are stored there, not the source control logs.

Any idea how I could solve this ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has no additional logs for Git version control in xcode.

Instead, you need to debug the issue by git commands with below aspects:

#### 1. Make sure the user.name and user.email has been configured

If you have not configured `user.name` and `user.email` for the local git repo or globally, then you can config them by:

```
git config --glogal user.name "user name"
git config --global user.email "email address"
```

And you can refer [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32649277/the-working-copy-project-name-failed-to-commit-files-couldnt-communicate-w) for the similar question.

#### 2. To get more detail information by git commands

In the local git repo, you can use `git status` to check if the modified files been tracked. Use the command `git commit -am 'message'` to check the detail output information.

Comment: thanks for this info, I made sure the step 1 was done already but I was just wondering if there were any logs directly from Xcode. I'm gonna try to commit everything via my terminal directly then